# Conditional find & replace

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements

Today I am stuck with this code while trying to replace a dot (.) but only if in the list from sheet1 does not match one of the values from another list of another sheet (same workbook). "**Argument NOT optional**" is the error but it would not give me any other hint.

```
Sub Filter(wsS As Worksheet, wsN As Worksheet, i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer, a As Integer)
'
' substitute Macro
'
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("a1").FormulaR1C1 = "Sorted"
    Set wsS = Sheets("sheet1")
    Set wsN = Sheets("non_confid")
    col1 = "A"
    col2 = "E"
    col3 = "C"
 
    For a = 1 To 200
         If wsS.Range(col1 & a) = wsN.Range("AB2:ab600") Then
            a = a + 1
            Else: Range(col1 & a).Replace What:=".", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
            a = a + 1
         End If
    Next
    
    Range("a1").AutoFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A:A"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    
    Range("a1").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
        With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 15773696
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    
    With Selection.Font
        .Color = -10477568
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$a$500"), , xlYes).Name = "Table1"
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
        
        Set wsS = Sheets("sheet1") 'this has assigned the worksheet sheet1 to wsS
        Set wsN = Sheets("non_confid") 'this has assigned the worksheet sheet1 to wsU
        
        i = 2
        
        For j = 2 To 300
            If Not IsEmpty(wsS.Range(col1 & j).Value) Then
                wsS.Range(col3 & i - 1).Value = wsS.Range(col1 & j).Value
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next
    
    Range("A:B").EntireColumn.Delete
    
        For k = 1 To 300
               If IsEmpty(wsS.Range(col1 & k).Value) Then
                    i = i + 1 'Exit For 'this jumps out of the loop, so no more copying.
               Else
                    wsN.Range(col2 & i).Value = wsS.Range(col1 & k).Value
                    i = i + 1
               End If
        Next

    Sheets("non_confid").Select
    Columns("A:G").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("e1").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Status").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<>"
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I also have some more columns that compare the final list with more lists to see if the result matches with any of their values. The trick is that since I have two sets of values, I do not wish to use 2 workbooks and the dot makes that difference

Answer (score 1):

The only required arguments for `Replace` are **What** and **Replacement**, which you have supplied.

I do not receive an error message about this but I do with this line:

```
If wsS.Range(col1 & a) = wsN.Range("AB2:ab600") Then
```

because you are trying to compare a single value with a `Range`.

(I'm assuming that wsS and wsN are set correctly to worksheets.)

This is the likely cause of any errrors. But as your error message is different I am suspicious that you are not posting your actual code, or enough of it for us to replicate your problem.

Comment: anyway, I believe I will be able to adapt the solution if offered a different version (declare new variables, etc.)